# Can you have two interdependent inputs in R Shiny that rely on other inputs?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm looking at having two sliders that should update together, based on some function. For example, one slider is the square root of the other. I want to be able to change either slider and for the other one to update reactively.

The following does work:

```
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  f = reactive(function(x) x^2)
  finv =reactive(function(x) sqrt(x))
    
    output$x <- renderUI({
      slider_s.value <- input$s
      default.slider_x <-  if (is.null(slider_s.value)) 1 else f()(slider_s.value)
                       sliderInput("x", "Select x:",
                                   min = 0, max=100,
                                   value = default.slider_x, step = 0.01,
                                   animate = animationOptions(interval = 600, loop = TRUE))
    })
    
    output$s <- renderUI({
      slider_x.value <- input$x
      default.slider_s <- if (is.null(slider_x.value)) finv()(1) else finv()(slider_x.value)
                       sliderInput("s", "Select s:",
                                   min = 0, max=10,
                                   value = default.slider_s, step = 0.01,
                                   animate = animationOptions(interval = 600, loop = TRUE))
    })
    
  }

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("One Way Reactive Slider"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             h4("Slider Inputs"),
             uiOutput('s'),
             uiOutput('x')
           ))
    
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, this doesn't.

```
library(shiny)

server = function(input, output) {  
  
  g = reactive(function(x) x^2 - input$slider)
  ginv =reactive(function(x) sqrt(x+ input$slider))
    
    output$slider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:",
                  min = 1, max = 100, value = 2)
    })
    
    output$x <- renderUI({
      slider_s.value <- input$s
      default.slider_x <-  if (is.null(slider_s.value)) 1 else g()(slider_s.value)
                       sliderInput("x", "Select x:",
                                   min = 0, max=100,
                                   value = default.slider_x, step = 0.01,
                                   animate = animationOptions(interval = 600, loop = TRUE))
    })
    
    output$s <- renderUI({
      slider_x.value <- input$x
      default.slider_s <- if (is.null(slider_x.value)) ginv()(1) else ginv()(slider_x.value)
                       sliderInput("s", "Select s:",
                                   min = 0, max=10,
                                   value = default.slider_s, step = 0.01,
                                   animate = animationOptions(interval = 600, loop = TRUE))
    })
    
  }

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("One Way Reactive Slider"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             h4("Slider Inputs"),
             uiOutput('slider'),
             uiOutput('s'),
             uiOutput('x')
           ))
    
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It messes up when the "Slider Input" is changed. Is there some way that I can get round this? I've seen other posts on here about constraining sliders but none seem to rely on other inputs like this.

Note that I want x = g(s) and s = ginv(x) which should be okay since g and ginv are inverses of each other!

Answer (score 0):

Some changes are required in `output$x <- RenderUI` code block to fix the slider values flickering issue.

```
output$x <- renderUI({
    slider_slider.value <- input$slider
    default.slider_x <-  if (is.null(slider_slider.value)) 1 else g()(slider_slider.value)
    sliderInput("x", "Select x:",
                min = 0, max=100,
                value = default.slider_x, step = 0.01,
                animate = animationOptions(interval = 600, loop = TRUE))
  })
```

Comment: This fixes the flickering but still doesn't do what I want. In this case, s depends on x but not the other way around.